# Receiving the appropriate Json model - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have been trying to figure out how the JSON payload is supposed to look when it is being received by my REST API for the UPDATE action. Currently I am taking each parameter for the json request and assigning it to a new object and then persisting that to the database. I know this isn't realistic if my project gets any larger. So how would I construct the Json so I can just call :Account to get the whole package instead of each parameter.

```
def update
    respond_with Account.update(params[:id], params[:account])
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh Never mind I ended up getting it.

```
{
    "created_at": "2013-02-04T21:23:06Z",
    "email": "dat_email@gmail.com",
    "updated_at": "2013-02-06T04:06:02Z",
    "username": "Rizowski"
}
```

I just needed to have the payload parameter on the Http request to be user assigned to the json above. I then took that and parsed it from json to a usable hash.

```
id = params[:id]
user = JSON.parse params[:user]

if User.update(id, user)
    render json: @user
else
    render :status => 400,
        :json => { :message => "Something went wrong with saving user changes."}
    return
end
```